# Autofac Azure Mobile Service integration issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I gets '..make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor autofac..'

**My controller:**

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private IAccountService _accountService;

    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
    ...
}
```

**My autofac configuration:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterType<AccountService>().As<IAccountService>().InstancePerRequest();
    var container = builder.Build();

    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Full error message:

```
Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProj.Api.Controllers.AccountController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProj.Engine.Services.Interfaces.IAccountService accountService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProj.Engine.Services.Interfaces.IAccountService)'.
```

Comment: Did you install Web API integration  'Autofac.WebApi' nuget package?

Comment: @MilenPavlov yes, sure
http://grab.by/DWrG

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have added inner exception message, may be it will help :)

Comment: Can you show the constructor for AccountService here?

Comment: Can you try this line in order to register your controller builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(AccountController).Assembly); ?

Comment: @TravisIllig actually there is no any constructor for AccountService.

Comment: @hugo got the same error with your approach to register the controller.

Comment: Do you have more than one IAccountService interface anywhere in the solution? Any way you could post a small repro solution somewhere to look at?

Comment: @TravisIllig,@hugo,@MilenPavlov  sorry it was my ignorancу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself. Actually the issue was that project is Azure Mobile Service.
It was my first experience with it and I have configured it as I used to do for WebApi. But as I understood after last googling this project type base on OWIN. 
That's good article about: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/19/autofac-and-azure-mobile-services-net-backend.aspx

So it should be like this:

```
 ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

 ConfigBuilder builder = new ConfigBuilder(options, (httpConfig, autofac) =>
 {
         autofac.RegisterInstance(new MyService()).As<IMyService>();
 });

 HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(builder);
```